# Looking for SQL request

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have datatable in Microsoft SQL 2012

[image: Datatable rows]

It is possible to select data values with newest key position with one request?
Or maybe not with one?

Result i want should be 10,20,30,50,70

Comment: Elaborate on your question, I find it tough to understand what exactly it is you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select data from tableName  where id in (select MAX(id) from tableName group by key)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it using the following:

```
SELECT data
FROM datatable
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT MAX(ID) latest_id
  FROM datatable
  GROUP BY key
)
```

This picks out the latest row for each key (going by incrementing ID). Then you simply only pick these rows using the `IN` which excludes the non-latest rows.

Comment: Why has this been downvoted twice? It is correct, returns exactly what was asked and the answer that was later accepted matches this precisely so it is clearly not incorrect.

Comment: Yes, this solution is ok, but danish solution is shorter. and probably runs a bit faster.

Comment: It's the same query (as it was posted first) formatted differently... I could remove the column alias `latest_id` and it would literally be the same. It runs at precisely the same speed. I don't think it's fair to downvote my answer because I put linebreaks in rather than leaving it all on one line!

Comment: Yes you are right. But live is not fair. :) By the way: i upvote tou answer.

Comment: In that case nevermind! I don't mind not having answer accepted, I thought you were explaining you downvoted the answer because it was longer + slower, neither of which I think are reasons.

Answer (score -2):

yes, it is:

```
select Data from table
where Key = (select max(Key) from table)
order by ID
```

This will output all Data with highest Key, assuming that highest=newest

Comment: No, this gets you the maximum key (12) and just picks the data from this, ordered  i.e. 40, 60, 70

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working. As the result i have 50: data on biggest key value